# FluentNhibernate and double relationhip between table

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have 2 tables,category and product.  A category is associated with many products so we have a relation one-to-many.  So when I want to map these tables I should add a product collection in the category table.  Or I have read in a the NHibernate tutorial that it's better to:

> Avoid putting a Products collection on the Category entity, as it is
>   possible that a  category can have hundreds, if not thousands, of
>   associated products. To load  the whole, huge collection of products
>   for a given category would be unwise  and would lead to an application
>   having unsatisfactory response times.

Is there any advice!!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to put a Reference to a category in the product class to have the relationship. Having a collection in the Category class is not forbidden only discouraged when having a lot products in it and accessing the products over the collection. NHibernate defaults to lazyload the product-collection in the category, so normally it's not a problem.